# How to add app icon to Xamarin Android app

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm struggling to add app icon to Actionbar. I've tried

```
ActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

but i got `NullReferenceExeption`
if anyone knows how to add it plz help.
thanks.
this is the code i have written

```html
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Bteg
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            ActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First welcome to StackOverflow (affectionately SO). One thing that will help you receive good answers is to ask good question. Instead of just saying "It didn't work" please expound and provide error output, a little more of the surrounding code to provide a better context. It is also very helpful to provide solutions you have tried. Again, welcome and I do hope you find a solution

Comment: I got NullReferenceExeption. that's the error output

Comment: Ok. But edit your question to provide this exception and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add these to your original post. Thank you

Comment: ok i added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you used `AppCompatActivity`, If you want to get the actionbar, you need to use following code.

```
  [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.dicon);

        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Here is running sceenshot.

[image]

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to mark it as answer(Click ✔ in the upper right corner of the answer), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Wow! it worked! thank u very much, BTW I'm new to Xamarin